# Count arguments

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I write this commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter values a and b (separate with space)"
read a b
echo $#
```

And I want to count how many arguments the user has entered. I try to count with `$#`, but the output is `0`.

What's the problem? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: There are no arguments; you read exactly one string from standard input, and you split that string into at most two strings. `$#` is the number of *command-line* arguments provided when the script was run.

Comment: It is possible to count how many values user has entered?

Comment: If you use `read -ra array`, you can `set -- "${array[@]}"`, which will override `$1`, `$2`, etc., and thus also `$#`.

Comment: @EdgarasAlšauskas, ...btw, you might want to reconsider your accepted-answer designation. Someone isn't allowed to delete their own answer, even if they want to, if it's marked accepted (at least, that's true with a positive score); and there are certainly more robust alternatives currently available..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use an array to read complete line and count # of words:

```
read -p "Enter values (separate with space): " -ra arr
```

```
Enter values (separate with space): abc foo bar baz 123
```

Then print no of words:

```
echo "No of words: ${#arr[@]}"
```

```
No of words: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd probably do it, without thinking too much about it. It's hacky to use the dummy `c` variable, but I find bash array's even more awkward.

```
read -r a b c

if [[ $c ]]
then
        echo "To much arguments"
elif [[ $a && $b ]]
        echo "Correct - 2 arguments"
else
        echo "Not enough arguments"
fi
```